# Не получается обновить PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, path

Привет. Не могу обновить PATH-variable на Ubuntu 16.04. Презаписываю путь, после чего делаю `export PATH`. Но при рестарте терминала, всё возвращается на круги своя. Везде советуют сделать именно так. Но, увы. Поможите!

Comment: Возможно это поможет: [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/5275890)

Comment: Пропишите PATH в ~/.profile

Comment: Я обычно правлю `~/.profile`. Задача скорее админская.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, не помогло.

Comment: @carapuz не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При старте в интерактивном режиме, **bash** считывает `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` и `~/.profile`. Вам надо поместить обновление **PATH** в один из этих файлов. Скорей все там уже есть настройка **PATH** и вам надо просто добавить нужные вам директории.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, это не помогло. Зашёл в profile, прописал PATH, но по-прежнему беда.

Comment: Открываю терминал... ну, собственно, наверное. Что там ещё может быть?

Comment: Как это определить?